# Unmarhsalling array of pointer of structure

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a requirement to connect to a third party application with a C interface, but I everything I tried so far, crashes the application while working with the `ImageArray.images` field.

One of its methods requires an structure declared as:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    Image **images;
} ImageArray;
```

The `Image` type is a simple structure, with only `int` fields (like width and height):

```
typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
} Image;
```

An image may be accessed first derefencing the array element, than dereferencing the `Image` struct. For example:

```
ImageArray imageArray = ... // initialize it somehow.
imageArray[0]->width
```

The function I'm trying to call from C# without success is declared as:

```
int Segment(Image *image, ImageArray **images);
```

So far, I've declared the following structures and methods to interface with the native library:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal struct Image
{
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal unsafe struct ImageArray
{
    public Int32 Size;
    public IntPtr Images;

}

public static extern int Segment([In] ref Image image, [Out] out IntPtr images);
```

Also, I've implemented the following wrapper, which triggers the error:

```
IntPtr imagesArrayPtr;
Segment(ref nImage, out imagesArrayPtr));

var imageArray = (ImageArray)Marshal.PtrToStructure(imagesArrayPtr, typeof(ImageArray));
var sz = imageArray.Size;
var ptr = imageArray.Images;
var images = new Image[imageArray.Size];
for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.Size; i++)
{
    images[i] = (Image)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Image));
    ptr = new IntPtr(ptr.ToInt32() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));
}
```

I removed the error checking to reduce the code size.

This example I came up while looking at other stack overflow questions.

How can I correctly implement this call?

**Update**: Calling `Segment` from C/C++ (error checking ommited):

```
Image *image;
ImageLoadFromFile("file.png", &image);

ImageArray *imageArray;
Segment(image, &imageArray);

for ( int i = 0; i < imageArray->size; i++ ) {
    const Image *img = imageArray[i];
    printf("width=%d height=%d\n", img->width, img->height);
}
```

The function `ImageLoadFromFile` loads the specified image at the first argument at its second argument, returning `true` if success (error checking ommited).

Comment: @Ðаn I'm not familiar with C++/CLI. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: C++ is not an option (boss orders...). I added a code snippet displaying the call to the `Segment()` method. Thanks for your time!